# The values of my 1st column are going into the index but the column name is the 1st column outside the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The values of my first column are going into the index but the column name is the first column outside the index, so I cannot use df.reset_index. For instance, my dataframe looks like this:

|  | CHA_NUMB | CHA_NAME | UN_CHA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m_3_1 | 12345 | lcha |
| 2 | t_1_2 | 12456 | lcha |
| 3 | blah | 90244 | lcha |
| 4 | blah | 23435 | lcha |

When it should look like this:

|  | CHA_NUMB | CHA_NAME | UN_CHA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | m_3_1 | 12345 |
| 1 | 2 | t_1_2 | 12456 |
| 2 | 3 | blah | 90244 |
| 3 | 4 | blah | 23435 |

I tried resetting the index but it didn't work. Resetting the index makes the dataframe look like this:

|  | index | CHA_NUMB | CHA_NAME | UN_CHA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | m_3_1 | 12345 | lcha |
| 1 | 1 | t_1_2 | 12456 | lcha |
| 2 | 2 | blah | 90244 | lcha |
| 3 | 3 | blah | 23435 | lcha |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then remove last column by indexing in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and last set columns names by original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().iloc[:, :-1].set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   CHA_NUMB CHA_NAME  UN_CHA_ID
0         1    m_3_1      12345
1         2    t_1_2      12456
2         3     blah      90244
3         4     blah      23435
```

Alternative:

```
cols = df.columns
df = df.reset_index().iloc[:, :-1]
df.columns = cols
```

EDIT: If first row of columns names not matched data you can omit columns names by `header=None` and `skiprows=1`, get columns names like RangeIndex, then use `usecols` for select first and third column and last set columns names by `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, 
                 header=None, 
                 skiprows=1, 
                 usecols=[0,2], 
                 names=['CHA_NUMB','UN_CHA_ID'])
    
print (df)
   CHA_NUMB  UN_CHA_ID
0         1      12345
1         2      12456
2         3      90244
3         4      23435
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I have a follow-up question.
I'm reading these dataframes (thousands of rows in each dataframe) from files using the for loop and there are 60 dataframes. All dataframes have the same format but only some of them were having this problem (almost 20). Now, when I use this command to solve the problem, the dataframes that were loaded correctly get messed up. Is there a way I can load all these dataframes correctly? And do you know why this problem is occurring in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadRaffae - Reason is like here - data are in 4 columns, columns names are only 3, so last column seems dont need. So problem is in data.

Comment: Actually, the data are in 21 columns but I need only 2 ['CHA_NUMB' and 'UN_CHA_ID], so I use "usecols = col_names" to get the desired columns only. I put the third column in the "usecols" because the values of the desired column were getting shifted to that column.

Comment: @MuhammadRaffae - One idea, added to answer like EDIT. Can you check it?

Comment: @jazrael That is PERFECT! Thank you so much! Have the best day! :)